# CSS Dropdown specific item smaller

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, wordpress-theming

i have a Problem with my Website..
I want to make a dropdown-item smaller.
Otherwise it will "plop" out of my theme..

I´m using WordPress..

Can anyone help me?!

This is the Website:
[MDS](http://www.managed-desktop-systems.de/)

The Problem is shown at the menu-point "Kontakt -> Presse"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if reduce width it will create problem when inner text is big in length so

change this properties if you like it as below..

```
ul#dropdown-menu li .sub-menu li a {
color: #252525;
width: 140px;
}

ul#dropdown-menu ul {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
right: 0;
width: 160px;
list-style: none;
display: none;
border: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
border-bottom: none;
background-color: white;
z-index: 35;
}
```

Comment: I am not getting what is the problem now, please can you explain it!

Comment: I think you tried with `width: 180px;` in `ul#dropdown-menu ul ` which I changed to `width: 160px;` after posting it, may be you have tried with previous version of my answer so you can see there a white space, please try again, and let me know is it fine?

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
#menu-item-38 ul, #menu-item-38 li{
    width:100px;
}
#menu-item-38 ul li a{
    width:80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi now **define** your **last** `submenu` width as like this

```
#menu-item-38 .sub-menu{
width:90px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have too many widths defined in the `ul#dropdown-menu`

```
ul#dropdown-menu ul li a = 160px ;
ul#dropdown-menu ul li = 180px  ;
```

Change 
`ul#dropdown-menu ul l`i to

```
ul#dropdown-menu ul li{width:160px; overflow:hidden;}
```

Make sure to add overflow:hidden